# Class 'App\users' not found in Laravel when i create users.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException in usercontroller.php line 21: Class 'APP\User' not found

**usercontroller.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use APP\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;


class usercontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::all();
        return view('admin/users', compct('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**User.php (it's in App/User.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I create to **users.blade.php** to listing user in Admin Panel but at last then i m click to a user then they have an error on screen please say what can i do

Comment: Instead of **use APP\User;** you can use **use App\User;**

Comment: @InzamamIdrees i m use this "use App\User;" but they give another error like this FatalErrorException in usercontroller.php line 21: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\compct()

Comment: Beceause it's compact() not compct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Typo

Change `use APP\User;` to `use App\User;`

It's case sensitive so they are not the same thing.

Comment: i m use this "use App\User;" but they give another error like this       
 FatalErrorException in usercontroller.php line 21: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\compct()

Answer (score 1):

please use User class in UserController with this namespace **App/User NOT APP/user**

Comment: i m use this "use App\User;" but they give another error like this FatalErrorException in usercontroller.php line 21: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\compct()

Comment: Beceause it's compact() not compct

Answer (score 1):

Change `use APP\User;` to `use App\User;`

Change also **compct** to **[compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::all();
    return view('admin/users', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: i m use this "use App\User;" but they give another error like this FatalErrorException in usercontroller.php line 21: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\compct()